# Можно ли и как в одном запросе обращаться сразу к трем таблицам?

Tags: php, sql, mysql

Можно ли и как в одном запросе обращаться сразу к трем таблицам?

Если не сложно, с примером.

SELECT a.name, b.name, c.name FROM table1 as a, table2 as b, table3 as c ON , а как дальше?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Конечно можно. Используя конструкцию `SELECT ... FROM ...`.
Названия полей должны указываться через запятую и лучше с сокращением ('.. AS ..').
Пример: 3 таблицы (table1, table2, table3). Нужно взять поля соответственной row1,row2,row3.

```
SELECT a.row1,b.row2,c.row3 FROM table1 as a, table2 as b, table3 as c`
```

Comment: SELECT a.name, b.name, c.name FROM table1 as a, table2 as b, table3 as c ON , а как дальше?

Comment: В таком случае конкретизируйте вопрос. Не очень ясно понимаю что вам необходимо. Прочитайте про оператор Join по ссылке с поста @ICE

Comment: Можно вместо явного Join (ON в sql запросе) использовать WHERE (иногда это понятнее)

Например

    ... WHERE a.id = b.id AND a.id = c.id ...

Answer (score 3):

JOIN: [wikipedia](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29), там есть примеры.

Answer (score 1):

Смотря какой результат запрос должен выдать по этим таблицам, кроме join рекомендую почитать и про UNION

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.name, b.name, c.name 
FROM table1 as a
full join table2 as b
on a.row=b.row
full join
table3 as c 
ON a.row=c.row
```

Так объединяются три таблицы без потери данных, если в одной из таблиц нет соответствия.

Если необходимо сохранять значения только из одной таблицы, используются `left join` и `right join`, в зависимости от того, какой стоит сохраняемая таблица от
`join`.